# Scrapy Can't Select By ID

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to **scrape** data for a school project but for some reason I can't figure out how to gt the data from the table on this page.  I'm testing out in scrapy shell and just not getting any data back.  Here's what I'm trying

```
scrapy shell https://www.psacard.com/pop/baseball-cards/1911/turkey-red-cabinets-t3-t9/51453

table = response.xpath('//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0"]/table/tbody')
```

this is returning `[]`

I've tried with the entire table class as well like such

```
table = response.xpath('//*[@class="clear interior-result-table pop-grid items psa table-striped dataTable no-footer dtr-inline"]')
```

and getting the same `[]` response

i'm stumped. any ideas?

Comment: Goto page source, if you could not find the dom you have used in xpath, it is a js page. For js page you need js rendering engine like splash.

For this simply do request as @Vezunchik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All data that you need is in another request. You can find it in developer tools in Chrome, for example. Check `https://www.psacard.com/Pop/GetItemTable?headingID=51453&categoryID=20003&isPSADNA=false&pf=0&_=1555080293549`. Even common GET request to this link will give you table rows.

Comment: I was also going to answer the same!

Comment: thank you!  when you say 'common get request' what exactly do you mean--ie how are you pulling the data this way?

Comment: I meant that you don't need any special headers or cookies, etc.

Comment: can i ask one quick thing?  how do you find that request in dev tools?  I'm checking the console, network etc, and can't find anything

Comment: Chrome, Dev tools, Network tab. Open it and refresh page, here is screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/2a2KbPl